# Sitecore OpenIdConnect ExternalUserBuild not being called on 2nd Login

Tags: federated-authentication, openid-connect

In my `Sitecore 9.1.1` instance I've almost successfully set up `Federated Authentication`.
The problem I'm currently trying to solve is the following:

The Login Button authenticates my user via Keycloak and my custom `ExternalUserBuilder` class gets called just fine.
The Logout Button deletes the user session in Keycloak.
But when I log in once again with the same browser then my custom `ExternalUserBuild` Code **doesn't** get called again. The user is authenticated against Keycloak.

Opening an incognito Browser and clicking the login calls the `ExternalUserBuilder` class as it used to.

So as long as I'm using the same browser it's not working properly.

Any idea what I missed?

This is my code:

**config**

```
 <pipelines>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <processor type="ST.Foundation.OKC.Identity.Pipelines.KeycloakIdentityProvider, ST.Foundation.OKC" resolve="true" />
      </owin.identityProviders>
      <!-- 
        Pipeline to handle OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotification AuthorizationCodeReceived event / callback. 
     -->
      <Keycloak.AuthorizationCodeReceived>
        <processor type="ST.Foundation.OKC.Identity.Pipelines.AuthorizationCodeReceived.MapClaims, ST.Foundation.OKC" resolve="true" />
      </Keycloak.AuthorizationCodeReceived>
    </pipelines>


    <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
        
        <mapEntry name="Keycloak" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>modulkatalog</site>
            <site>swk-privatkunden</site>
            <site>shared-site</site>
          </sites>


          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
            <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Keycloak']" />
          </identityProviders>


          <externalUserBuilder type="ST.Foundation.OKC.Identity.Provider.UserBuilder, ST.Foundation.OKC" resolve="true">
            <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
          </externalUserBuilder>
        </mapEntry>

      </identityProvidersPerSites>


      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider id="Keycloak" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" >
          <param desc="name">Keycloak</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>Log in with Keycloak</caption>
          <domain>extranet</domain>
          <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
            <!-- IDP Transformation -->
            <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
            <!-- Name Identifier Claim-->
            <transformation name ="Name identifier claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
            <transformation name="map role to idp" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="idp" value="Keycloak" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="extranet\OKC" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>
      <!--List of all shared transformations-->
      <sharedTransformations>
        <transformation name ="Shared Name identifier claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
            <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" />
          </sources>
          <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
            <claim name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" />
          </targets>
          <keepSource>true</keepSource>
        </transformation>
      </sharedTransformations>
      <!--Property mappings initializer-->

      <propertyInitializer type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication'>
        <maps hint='list'>
          <map name='Name' type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication' resolve='true'>
            <data hint='raw:AddData'>
              <source name='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name' />
              <target name='FullName' />
            </data>
          </map>          
          <map name='emailclaim' type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication' resolve='true'>
            <data hint='raw:AddData'>
              <source name='"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress' />
              <target name='Email' />
            </data>
          </map>        
          </maps>
        </propertyInitializer>

    </federatedAuthentication>
```

**KeycloakIdentityProvider.cs**

```
  var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions(authenticationType)
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                RedirectUri = GetCallbackUrl(),
               // PostLogoutRedirectUri = _logoutUri,
                ClientId = _clientId,
                Authority = _issuer,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,  
                AuthenticationType = GetAuthenticationType(), 
                UseTokenLifetime = false, 
                CookieManager = CookieManager,
                Scope = _scope,             
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    
                },
                

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification) =>
                    {
                      
                        if (notification.Exception != null)
                        {
                            Log.Info($"Keycloak authorization fail: "+ notification.Exception.Message, this);


                            notification.HandleResponse();

                            if (notification.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323")|| notification.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX20803"))
                            {
                                notification.HandleResponse();
                                /* This line of code is the key to solve error 
                               IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. 
                               The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.
                               */
                                notification.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }                           
                            
                        }


                        notification.HandleResponse();
                        notification.Response.Redirect(_redirectUri);


                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },                   
                    MessageReceived = n =>
                    {                        
                        Log.Info("messagereceived errordescription=" + n.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription, this);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
                    {
                        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            //PKCE Implementation
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }

                        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                                                                 
                            var revokeProperties = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseRevoke?.Properties?.Dictionary;
                            var postLogoutUri = notification.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                            {
                                if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                                {
                                    // transform to absolute
                                    var request = notification.Request;
                                    postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                                }
                            }                           

                            var nonce = string.Empty;
                            if (revokeProperties != null && revokeProperties.ContainsKey("nonce"))
                            {
                                //nonce is always empty on the first login and login 
                                //not empty on the second login and then logout without starting with a new inkognito browser
                                nonce = $"?ReturnUrl={postLogoutUri}&nonce={revokeProperties["nonce"]}";
                            }
                        
                            notification.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutUri;
                           
                            return Task.FromResult(0);

                        }
                    

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = ProcessAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                }

            };
                                   
            args.App.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
        }
```

**LogoutController**

```
   var authenticationTypes = new string[] {
                                                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                                                        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                                                        "Keycloak"};
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl }, authenticationTypes);

           
            AuthenticationManager.Logout();
```

Comment: Can you try the login/logout on a incognito window once ?

Comment: As I've mentioned, I did that. And it is only working there as well, wenn I close the window after the 1st login/logout and open a new one again for the 2nd login. Than the custom externalUserBuilder get's called also on the 2nd login

Comment: did your keycloak integration worked? Any steps you can provide?